# Is there anyway I can access binary file that store in SAS?

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I use a PROC MIXED to build the mixed-effect model. In my PROC MIXED, I have the 'STORE' statement which produce the statistical analysis and store in the binary file format. 
(http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect022.htm )

The code looks something like this:

```
PROC MIXED data=dat; 
class id; 
model height = Age; 
random intercept;
STORE OUT = plm; 
run;
```

I am wondering if there is anyway I can access this file (plm).

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean access?  The doc you linked to describes how the file, and how it can be used in PROC PLM.  What are you trying to achieve?  You may want to look into ODS, if you want to get results from your model into a SAS dataset.

Comment: The problem is that in PROC PLM, when scoring the new data set, PLM doesn't take the random effect into an account (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_plm_a0000000126.htm). That is why I want to access the binary file so that I can score the data set manually. Yeah, I was thinking about using ODS, but that will take a few steps.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? If you have SAS 9.4+ (SAS/STAT13.1+) it has the new CODE statement available that generates a SAS program to do the scoring.

Comment: @Reeza - Are you talking about plm procedure? If so, then I'm afraid that wouldn't work. The problem is that proc PLM, "SCORE" statement, doesn't take the random effect into an account.

Comment: If you want to generate scores you can use CODE, but that won't do any other model comparisons. SAS doesn't recommend modifying the score file so you may want to contact SAS Tech Support to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: What do you mean by use CODE? Right now, i'm using ESTIMATE statement in proc mixed to estimate the output for each ID. The problem is that I have a lot of ID, using ESTIMATE doesn't seem so effective.